# Create function in R

Tags: r, function, data-mining

I'm trying to create a function that will take a vector `x` and return a vector `Result`, such that `Result[i]` contains the standard deviation of the `x` vector *with the `i`<sup>th</sup> element omitted*.

Comment: What have you tried (please show your code)? What, specifically, about what you have tried does not work as you expect?

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
f <- function(x){

    y <- numeric(0)

    for(i in 1:length(x)){

        y[i] <- sd(x[-i])

    }

    return(y)

 }

 x <- 1:10

 > f(x)
 [1] 2.738613 2.934469 3.073181 3.162278 3.205897 3.205897 3.162278 3.073181 2.934469 2.738613
```

Comment: Nice trick with the `x[-i]` ! With `sapply` it can be even better!

Comment: Hi Janos, I wanted to comment earlier on your answer, but did not have enough rep yet. I was indeed wondering why you choose `sapply` over a `for loop`? Is it a speed thing or has it other benefits? Tnx

Comment: Usually `sapply` is faster. It's also more elegant and shorter. But most importantly, it helps you get rid of the mutable `y` variable. In general, mutable variables are troublesome, and they make a program not thread-safe. It's good to avoid them as much as possible, and functional languages like R encourage you to do so.

Comment: Tnx, that makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
fun <- function(x) {
  sapply(1:length(x), function(i) sd(x[-i]))
}
fun(x)
```

**(just for the record...)**

This was my original solution before I saw [@Joost](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3830362/joost)'s

```
fun <- function(x) {
  index <- 1:length(x)
  sd.without.ith <- function(index) {
    sd(x[index != i])
  }
  sapply(index, sd.without.ith)
}
x <- 40:50
fun(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun(ctional):

```
require(functional)

f <- function(x) sapply(seq(length(x)), Compose(`-`, Curry(`[`, x), sd))
f(1:3)
## [1] 0.7071068 1.4142136 0.7071068
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the combination of answers

```
f <- function(x) combn(rev(x), length(x)-1, FUN=sd)
f(1:3)
# [1] 0.7071068 1.4142136 0.7071068
```